# PHP sort array by same value twice

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array with show names like this:

```
$shows = array('morning_show_15_02_2014_part2.mp3',
'morning_show_15_02_2014_part1.mp3',
'morning_show_14_02_2014_part2.mp3',
'morning_show_14_02_2014_part1.mp3',
'morning_show_13_02_2014_part2.mp3',
'morning_show_13_02_2014_part1.mp3');
```

So the list look like:

`morning_show_15_02_2014_part2.mp3
morning_show_15_02_2014_part1.mp3
morning_show_14_02_2014_part2.mp3
morning_show_14_02_2014_part1.mp3
morning_show_13_02_2014_part2.mp3
morning_show_13_02_2014_part1.mp3`

This is what i get when i loop the directory.

But the list should look like this:

`morning_show_15_02_2014_part1.mp3
morning_show_15_02_2014_part2.mp3
morning_show_14_02_2014_part1.mp3
morning_show_14_02_2014_part2.mp3
morning_show_13_02_2014_part1.mp3
morning_show_13_02_2014_part2.mp3`

Still ordered by date, but part 1 is first and then comes part 2.

How can i get this list into right order?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your problem is that you want to order by date descending and by part ascending. Only chance is to do that in a custom sort function where you parse the filename. Have a look at [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Code is prett nasty but i got what i was looking for:

```
public function getMp3ListAsJSONArray() {
        $songs = array();
        $mp3s = glob($this->files_path . '/*.mp3');

        foreach ($mp3s as $key => $mp3Source) {
            $mp3Source = basename($mp3Source);
            $mp3Title = substr($mp3Source, 4);
            $mp3Title = substr($mp3Title, 0, -4);
            $mp3Title = basename($mp3Source, ".mp3");
            $mp3Title = str_replace('_', ' ', $mp3Title);
            $mp3Title = ucfirst($mp3Title);

            $songs[$key]['title'] = $mp3Title;
            $songs[$key]['mp3'] = urldecode($this->files_url . '/' . $mp3Source);
        }

        rsort($songs);

        $pairCounter = 1;
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
            $playlist[$pairCounter][] = $value;
            $counter = $counter + 1;

            if($counter == 2) {
                $pairCounter    = $pairCounter + 1;
                $counter        = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach ($playlist as $show) {
            $finalList[] = $show[1];
            $finalList[] = $show[0];
        }

        $finalList = json_encode($finalList);

        return $finalList;
    }
```

Output is like i described in the topic.

Comment: This relies heavily on the name being the same for every file. You will have to keep that format going on for every future file aswell.

Comment: Yes i understood that and i kept that in my mind. I ask client about that and they said it is ok and they can consider that.

Comment: You could implement an extra function to check for the correct format. E.g. check character length etc. Just to prevent wrong data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array sort

Here is an example for you

http://techyline.com/php-sorting-array-with-unique-value/

Answer (score 0):

You must definitely write your own string comparision function. Remember that you have 2 different comparisons. The first compares the first parts for the filenames as strings. The second part compares the numbers, where 20 comes after 2. This is a natural number sorting for the second part. The third part is after the last dot in the filename. This will be ignored.

```
<?php

function value_compare($a, $b) {
    $result = 0;
    $descending = TRUE;

    $positionA = strpos($a, 'part');
    $positionB = strpos($b, 'part');

    if ($positionA === $positionB) {
        $compareFirstPart = substr_compare($a, $b, 0, $positionA + 1);
        if ($compareFirstPart === 0) {

            $length = 0;
            $offset = $positionA + strlen('part');
            $positionDotA = strrpos($a, '.');
            $positionDotB = strrpos($b, '.');
            $part2A = '';
            $part2B = '';

            if ($positionDotA !== FALSE) {
                $part2A = substr($a, $offset, $positionDotA);
            } else {
                $part2A = substr($a, $offset);
            }

            if ($positionDotB !== FALSE) {
                $part2B = substr($b, $offset, $positionDotB);
            } else {
                $part2B = substr($b, $offset);
            }

            $result = strnatcmp($part2A, $part2B);
        } else {
            $result = $compareFirstPart;
            if ($descending) {
                $result = -$result;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$shows = array('morning_show_15_02_2014_part2.mp3', 'morning_show_15_02_2014_part1.mp3', 'morning_show_14_02_2014_part2.mp3', 'morning_show_14_02_2014_part1.mp3', 'morning_show_13_02_2014_part2.mp3', 'morning_show_13_02_2014_part1.mp3');


usort($shows, 'value_compare');

var_dump($shows);

?>
```